# Update 2 tables

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I'm on oscommerce. I need update my products_quantity but i have just the products_name

first table
PRODUCTS
--products_id
--products_quantity

PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION
--products_id
--products_name

My first test :

```
UPDATE `products` 
SET `products_quantity`='8'
where `products_id` = (SELECT `products_id` FROM `products_description` WHERE `products_name`='TOP CAISSE PLETSCHER')
```

Bad syntaxe

my second test

```
UPDATE `products` 
SET `products_quantity`='8'
where `products_id` = "SELECT `products_id` FROM `products_description` WHERE `products_name`='TOP CAISSE PLETSCHER'"
```

No error but my product isn't update. I think this method isn't support by my mysql version : 3.23.58

My third test :

```
UPDATE `products`
SET `products`.`products_quantity`='8'
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `products_description`
WHERE `products`.`products_id` = `products_description`.`products_id`
AND `products_description`.`products_name`='TOP CAISSE PLETSCHER'
```

I have this error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'FROM  `products`  INNER  JOIN  `products_description`  WHERE  `products`.`produc' at line 1
```

I'm running out of solution. If you could tell me what was wrong, I'd appreciate.

I'm using MySQL 3.23.58

Comment: I think you can do `UPDATE products INNER JOIN products_description SET products.products_quantity='8' WHERE...`

Comment: Is that MySQL version correct?  MySQL 3?!  We're on 5.6 now.

Comment: You're using software from ca. 2000! Upgrade.

Comment: I know that i have an obsolete version but i'm not the sysadmin. will test your answer Rocket. Thx for your help.

Comment: Have do two other test but don't work. [pastie](http://pastie.org/8534240) 1) error near FROM 2) error near products_description

Comment: Well is impossible with this mysql version. I resolve my problem with a php script with 2 query. Thx for your time :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that You're using PHP to connect to database. 
Can't You just use two queries to this?

First,

```
SELECT `products_id` FROM `products_description` WHERE `products_name`='TOP CAISSE PLETSCHER'
```

, then save result to array variable, and in loop update, for example:

```
foreach($result_array as $id) {
    UPDATE `products` 
    SET `products_quantity`='8'
    WHERE `products_id` = $id
}
```

Try and let us know if it helps.

Comment: my last comment : "Well is impossible with this mysql version. I resolve my problem with a php script with 2 query. " But thx for your answer ;)

Comment: Oh. OK. I didn't notice "show all comments" so I didn't know about it :) However, question remained unanswered, You can post answer and accept it on Your own ;)

Comment: It s the same conclusion.I'm not patting myself for losing 6 hours of my time to do a multi update on a mysql version that does not have this feature. Have a nice day;)